# How to reduce heap size in JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, jvm, visualvm

My JavaFX is using a serious about of memory. How can i reduce this amount?[image]

Is there a way to reduce the heap size and how do i do that in intellij?

---

I look at a few other questions but none seem to answer my question
[Does it make sense to call System.gc() and Thread.sleep() when working on Bitmaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673642/does-it-make-sense-to-call-system-gc-and-thread-sleep-when-working-on-bitmap)
[Is there a way to lower Java heap when not in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952568/is-there-a-way-to-lower-java-heap-when-not-in-use)
But i still dont know how to do it if its possible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the maximum memory usage for JVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493913/how-to-set-the-maximum-memory-usage-for-jvm)

Comment: See linked question on how to limit memory usage. Calling `System.gc` would probably not help in this situation, as the heap is mostly unused (although allocated).

Comment: Where do I set -Xms<memory> and -Xmx<memory>

Answer (score 0):

you can set -Xms and -Xmx under run -> edit configuration -> VM Options